# cocos2d-x 3.6 error: Error running command, return code: 1

Tags: c++, cmake, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a problem with cocos2d-x 3.6, I installed the program and create my first hello world file found in the program, but when I try to run, I get the following error, someone could tell me how to fix it and explain why it happened the error

> cocos run -s ~/MyCompany2/MyGame -p linux
>
> Running command: compile
>
> Building mode: debug
>
> running: 'cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DDEBUG_MODE=ON ..'
>
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>
> -- Detecting C compile features
>
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/g++ -- works
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>
> -- Detecting CXX compile features
>
> -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
>
> It appears you are builing natively for Linux with GCC
>
> -- OpenGL include dirs: /usr/include
>
> -- GLEW include dirs: /usr/include
>
> -- PkgConfig found
>
> -- checking for module 'glfw3'
>
> --   package 'glfw3' not found
>
> CMake Error at cocos2d/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136
>    (message):
>
> Could NOT find GLFW3 (missing: GLFW3_LIBRARIES GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR)
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
>
> cocos2d/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:343
>
> (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
>
> cocos2d/cmake/Modules/FindGLFW3.cmake:152
>
> (find_package_handle_standard_args)
>
> cocos2d/cmake/Modules/CocosBuildHelpers.cmake:44 (find_package)
>
> cocos2d/CMakeLists.txt:187 (cocos_find_package)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>
> See also "/home/jmuniz/MyCompany2/MyGame/linux-build/CMakeFile/CMakeOutput.log".
>
> Error running command, return code: 1

Answer (score 2):

The way to read errors in your build chain is typically from the top down; find the first thing marked "error" and fix that.

In this case, the first error is:

```
CMake Error at cocos2d/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:136 (message):

Could NOT find GLFW3 (missing: GLFW3_LIBRARIES GLFW3_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

and right above it the very helpful:

```
-- package 'glfw3' not found
```

So, it seems that what you're building requires this glfw3, and it can't find it.

I'm guessing that it's this: http://www.glfw.org/

You should check that you have that. If you don't, download it and install it appropriately for your system (which may, depending on what OS you're running, be as easy as finding it in your package manager), and try again.